# Transpose data frame based on a name column

Tags: r, dataframe, transpose

I would like to transpose a data frame using a name column to create new column names. Here is my input:

```
Name        X   Y   Z
sample1_A   1   2   3
sample1_B   3   2   1
sample2_A   1   2   3
sample2_B   3   2   1
```

And expected output:

```
Name    XA  XB  YA  YB  ZA  ZB
sample1 1   3   2   2   3   1   
sample2 1   3   2   2   3   1
```

I though I could you transpose function, but I am not sure how to deal with column and row names.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are those really `row.names` or is it a column called `Name`? The way you show it makes it look like the latter. Could you share the data with `dput()` so it is copy/pasteable and the structure is unambiguous?

Comment: It is actually the latter, how do you suggest to call it in the post, so I can edit it?

Comment: Try `library(tidyverse); df %>% separate(Name, into = c("Sample", "Name")) %>% gather(Key, Value, -Sample, -Name) %>% unite(Res, Key, Name, sep = "") %>% spread(Res, Value)`

Comment: I would just say "...using part of my `Name` column to create new column names".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `dcast` from `data.table` which can take multiple `value.var` columns

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(df1)[, c("Name", "grp") := tstrsplit(Name, "_")], 
               Name ~grp, value.var = c("X", "Y", "Z"), sep = "") 
#      Name XA XB YA YB ZA ZB
#1: sample1  1  3  2  2  3  1
#2: sample2  1  3  2  2  3  1
```

Comment: thanks, but would it be possible not to specify values in 'value.var' because in the real dataset there multiple value.var

Comment: and have a more flexible way of appending suffixes, e.g. _A instead of just A

Comment: @user2904120  You can use the column names i.e. `names(df1)[-1]` i.e. `dcast(setDT(df1)[, c("Name", "grp") := tstrsplit(Name, "_")], Name ~grp, value.var = names(df1)[2:4], sep="")`

Comment: great, and is there any way to be more flexible appending suffixes, to add "_A" instead of "A"

Comment: @user2904120  Just remove the `sep=""` or use `sep="_"`